# How to copy files with names that begin with substring?

Tags: command-line

I want to copy all the files that **begin with two digits followed by an underscore**.
My code below did not copy any files to the `KIRC` folder.

```
cp -R  ~/KIRP/[0-9][0-9]_* ~/KIRC/
```

Example contents of the `KIRP` folder:

```
11_abc.py
9_efg.R
hij_12.csv
```

Expected output:
11_abc.py
9_efg.R

Comment: `9_efg.R` has only one digit before the `_`.

Comment: please add `observed output` to your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`9_efg.R` doesn't match that pattern as there's only one digit before the `_`. `11_abc.py` does though. Maybe you tried that from the `fish` shell that doesn't support the `[...]` glob operator.

If you want to copy files whose name starts with a number between 0 and 99 followed by `_` regardless of how many digits are used to represent that number (including `000_x`, `1_y`, `11_z`), you can use the zsh shell which has a glob operator for that:

```
cp -R  ~/KIRP/<0-99>_* ~/KIRC/
```

Or

```
zsh -c 'cp -R  ~/KIRP/<0-99>_* ~/KIRC/'
```

From another shell.

With the `bash` shell, you can do something equivalent with:

```
shopt -s extglob failglob
cp -R ~/KIRP/*(0)[123456789]?([0123456789])_* ~/KIRC/
```

That is matching any number of `0`s followed by a digit from 1 to 9 (not using `[1-9]` as in bash contrary to zsh, that generally matches hundreds of different characters) followed by an optional digit from 0 to 9. We need `failglob` to avoid copying a file named literally `*(0)[123456789]?([0123456789])_*` if there's no match.

Beware that for files of type *directory*, that copies the directories and all their contents, `R`ecursively. To exclude files of type *directory*, with `zsh`:

```
cp ~/KIRP/<0-99>_*(^/) ~/KIRC/
```

(bash has no equivalent).

Or to copy any of those files found under any level of subdirectory under `~/KIRP`

```
cp ~/KIRP/**/<0-99>_*(D^/) ~/KIRC/
```

(remove the `D` to exclude those in hidden directories).

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`, you can type `cp -R ~/KIRP/[0-9]?([0-9])_* ~/KIRC/`. The extblob option should be set (see `echo $BASHOPTS`). But this would copy files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy "files only" from a directory and its (nested) subdirectories into a "flat" directory.

That is a job for `find`:

```bash
marco@minestrone ~/temp [0]
$ ls -lhvF KIRP
insgesamt 0
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 18:54 9_efg.R
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 18:54 11_abc.py
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 19:00 23_fdsjal.txt
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 19:00 55_adwf.md
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 18:54 hij_12.csv
marco@minestrone ~/temp [0]
$ ls -lhvF KIRC
insgesamt 0
marco@minestrone ~/temp [0]
$ find ~/temp/KIRP -type f -name "[0-9][0-9]_*" -exec cp {} ~/temp/KIRC \;
marco@minestrone ~/temp [0]
$ ls -lhvF KIRC
insgesamt 0
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 19:01 11_abc.py
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 19:01 23_fdsjal.txt
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 Feb 26 19:01 55_adwf.md
```

where `-type f`  limits the search to files, `-name` holds the regex for your file-names and `-exec` tells find what to do with the results.